# Azure Devops: Pull request reviews: link a task

Tags: azure-devops, task, pull-request

Linking a task inside a pull request can be done by using a hashtag. For example #12345. But when you would open the task, there is a Description added which includes only:
"Mentioned in PR 8765: PullRequestName".

Is it possible that the comments (or some comments) written in the review will end up in the task-description from the task without opening the actual pull-request-review again ?

[image: Task with a description included automatically due to a remark from a Pull Request]
Thanks
Cedric

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the comments (or some comments) written in the
> review will end up in the task-description from the task without
> opening the actual pull-request-review again ?

I am afraid that this is currently not possible in azure devops. Show "`Mentioned in PR XX: XXX`" in the task description. This is by design, and azure devops does not provide a syntax for displaying pull request comments in task description.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.